# Fallo al implementar un dismissible() en un container de un ListView.builder en un StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy tratando de implementar un dismissible() en un container de un ListView.builder en un StreamBuilder, el problema es que no hace nada, es decir una vez hago hot reload tengo el container pero no puedo hacer la acción de deslizar, aquí adjunto el código, gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Pd: acabo de añadir el StreamBuilder tal y como me han solicitado, espero su respuesta, muchas gracias, perdone la demora, no me había percatado de que habían respondido a mi publicación, muchas gracias.

No agrego mensaje de error en consola debido a que no me aparece ninguno, si necesitan algún dado mas, díganmelo y de inmediato lo subo.

```dart
//metodo para contruir los containers dinamicos
    _contenedorPrueba3(BuildContext context, List<PruebasModel> pruebas, int i){
  final registroBloc = MarcasBloc();
  return Dismissible(
    key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      boxShadow:[
                        BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius:3,
                          color: Colors.black12,
                          spreadRadius: 3
                        ),
                      ] 
                    ),
                      child: Text(pruebas[i].prueba, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),)
                  ),
                  /*onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'marcas', arguments: pruebas[i]);
                  },*/
                  onDismissed: (d){
                    registroBloc.eliminarPorTipo(pruebas[i].prueba);
                    registroBloc.eliminarPruebaPorNombre(pruebas[i].prueba);
                  },
  );

}

// buid de la app
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pruebas'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: pruebasContenedor(context),
);
  }



// streamBuilder

pruebasContenedor( BuildContext context) {
  final registroBloc = MarcasBloc();
  registroBloc.obtenerTodosRegistros();
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: registroBloc.registrosStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      registroBloc.obtenerTodosRegistros();
        final pruebas = snapshot.data;
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (pruebas.length == 0){
                      return Center(child: Text('Pulsa el boton + para añadir una prueba'),);
      }
      return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: pruebas.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i){
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children:<Widget>[

                  _contenedorPrueba3(context, pruebas, i),
                  SizedBox(height: 7,),
                  ] 
                ),
      );
            },
  );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el método donde se encuentra el StreamBuilder?

Comment: Buenas @diegoveloper ya he subido el streamBuilder tal y como me pidió